# Scrape HTML page with Javascript into Excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, selenium

Hoping one of you guys can help me here.  I'm trying to import data into excel from this webpage as well as some others that are the same website: https://re.po.st/qZZYQJ - basically I want to take the total clicks figure: 322,627 and have that in a column beside the URL in excel. I tried using importhtml and importxml in google spreadsheets but could not get it to work. I believe it is because this element is rendered in javascript? Does anyone know how to get this element? Is there a VBA code I could use. I'm not the most technical person so my apologies if I'm overseeing some things.

Mike

Comment: When I've been faced with the task of pulling data from a web page dynamically generated with javascript, I've turned to [Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/).

Comment: is there an example somewhere that I can see this done? Or the code for it?

Comment: If you go to the link, they document with examples.

Comment: Struggling with this application. The list of URLS will be in column A anyway somebody could quickly show the code to retrieve the 'total clicks figure' in column B using selenium?

Comment: This is my attempt but I feel it is woefully inept. any thoughts?

Sub test()
    Dim driver As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
    Set driver = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
    driver.Start "chrome", "https://re.po.st/pFYE5z"  'Starts the browser
    
    Dim data1
    data1 = driver.findElementByClassName("reports-total-table total-summ").GetData()
    Sheet3.[A1].Value = data1
    
    driver.stop 'Stops the browser
End Sub

Comment: You will need to get the id of the tag you want. Do you know how to do that? I right click and 'Inspect  element' to view the html of the page I'm interested in. For instance, when I do this on your sheet, I see that the closest tag to the number you want with an id is "squidtotaltable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function test(byval strLocation as string) as string
    Dim driver As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
    Set driver = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
    driver.Start "chrome", "https://re.po.st"
    driver.Open strLocation
    Dim data1
    data1 = driver.FindElementById("sguidtotaltable").FindElementByTagName("span").Text
    test = data1
    driver.stop 'Stops the browser
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for this. You are actually a lifesaver! Is there anyway to have this so that it will do it for more than one (ie. [A1] qZZYQJ , [A2] EXS15J, etc. ) so if I had those listed in column A can vba return all those values in column B?

Comment: I've updated the function to take a value in (such as "qZZYQJ") and it will return the value. You can actually call this function in Column B passing the cell in Column A as the input. `=test(A1)`

Comment: Hi Just taking a look at this now, not sure I'm implementing it 100% correctly. Are you saying I could use it as a sort of function? When I have implemented the new code as a module the first line is red. When I run it I recieve a "Expected: end of statement" - apologize for being such a newb :s

Comment: Ahhh I believe you meant to write function? I did this and I think it is working ! Will check back after fiddling with it.

Comment: Working like a charm. Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: Good catch on the Function keyword. Be aware, this is not the best way to do this. Another sub that sets the values with a loop would be better. With the method provided, all cells will re-pull the values every time the sheet is re-calculated.

Comment: Yes, I realized this happened when I tried to save the document and the functions started running all over again... I had to eventually quit excel. Alternatively, I suppose I could run the function, and copy and paste the values in a seperate column. I can try working on the loop. I thought the Sub would be best originally. Any direction you could point me in would for getting this done in a loop be fantastic.